# Stripe.js is not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure what's going on, but it doesn't look like `stripe.js` is loading within my RoR application.  I'm attempting to load it on a per-view basis (since I don't want JS bloat on other pages).  I have moved it to the main layout page (application.js) however that didn't make a difference.

> views/packages/new.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>
    <a class="login-logo" href="#">
      <%= image_tag "neo-logo.svg", alt: "Kernel-Ops - Network Ops Logo" %>
    </a>
  </h1>

  <br/>

  <div class="row login-container column-seperation">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <h2 class="text-center">You're almost done!  We just need to collect your payment information.</h2>
      <br/>
      <br/>
        <div class="row">
          <div align="center" class="col-md-12">
            <%= render 'form' %>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> views/packages/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag packages_path, id: "payment_form" do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'package_id', @package.id %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'email', current_user.email %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v2/" %>
  <script type="text/javascript"> Stripe.setPublishableKey("<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>")</script>

  <div class="form-group text-left">
    <%= label_tag "Card Number", nil, required: true, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, class: "form-control", "data-stripe" => "number" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group text-left">
    <%= label_tag "Card Verification (CVV)", nil, required: true, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :card_verification, nil, class: "form-control", "data-stripe" => "cvv" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group text-left">
    <%= label_tag "Card Expiration", nil, required: true, class: "control-label" %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= select_tag :exp_month, options_for_select(Date::MONTHNAMES.compact.each_with_index.map { |name,i| ["#{i+1} - #{name}", i+1] }), include_blank: false, "data-stripe" => "exp-month", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= select_tag :exp_year, options_for_select((Date.today.year..(Date.today.year+10)).to_a), include_blank: false, "data-stripe" => "exp-year", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br/><br/>

  <%= submit_tag "Submit Payment", class: "btn btn-success pull-right" %>
  <%= link_to "Cancel", :back, { :class => "btn btn-danger pull-right", :style => "margin-right: 15px;" } %>
<% end %>
```

I'm looking in the Chrome debugger under the network tab and there is no reference to `Stripe`.  Since there are quite a few JS scripts already being loaded, I've also used the script search feature to confirm it's not there.

Where is it?!

In the end, if I attempt to submit my form I get an error:

`This customer has no attached payment source`

Which makes sense since `Stripe.js` can't do it's thing.

**Quick Update**

Moved the inline call to the bottom of my layout instead of within the form, now I get:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined` in the console window.  Interestingly, this is what my developer window shows me which indicated that Stripe.js loaded, but it still is acting like it didn't:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a copy of you application.js? Make sure you are loading it at the proper time? i.e. Some other JS libraries might need to load before stripe.js can be loaded.

Comment: @ZackHerbert I'm not loading it via `application.js` it's loaded inline with the view... note line 4 of the _form partial.

Comment: It looks like turbolinks was causing an issue... ended up disabling it and all works now.  go figure